# How can I get "while" faster than a cursor in this case?

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, cursor, while-loop

Currently I have to work a bit more with SQL Server and I've read about cursors and how you should try to avoid them, because they're using a lot of resources and because they're slow.

Now I've tried to do some basic stuff with the cursor and tried to rebuild it with a while loop. At the end the cursor was ~10x faster than the while loop, while resources were about 60% to 40%.

Maybe because I have a strange example exercise?

This is about the exercise I gave myself:

- Iterate through a table, this table has exactly one column: "Names", containing about 1000 names.
- Print each name separately.

It's pretty easy with the cursor, but for the while-loop I need a counter or something. As the table has no index, I can't use that. So my solution was, that I created a temporary table, added all names to the table and include an index (or a row number). But the insert-operation takes about 95% of the time and at the end the while-loop is slower than the cursor.

Edit:
Another thing I tried was to use a `WITH Names_Rows AS...` and added `Row_Number()` as column and then used the while loop to iterate through the `Names_Rows` construct. But that took even longer.

Did I miss an easy way to iterate through a table using while without having an index?

Comment: Your task of looping through a list and printing each name separately is not typically performed in a database; it's usually done in the UI. We generally don't loop through things and perform operations on one record at a time. Instead, we think of things in terms of sets, and perform operations on the sets.

Comment: @DOK: My little "exercise" may not be typical, but it's based on a real situation, where it was needed to loop through a table directly on the database.

Comment: Please post test code.  What business problem are you trying to simulate.  To get all the rows in a table you can use select * from tableName.

Comment: @BalamBalam: Business problem is, that I have a function, that needs a single value. Maybe it's not the best function or the best way, but that's just the way it is at the moment.

Comment: @Feroc: It's still not clear what you are trying to achieve - do you have a single string value with 1000 comma-separated names that you are trying to split up, 1000 rows of a single value that you are trying to join up into a single comma-separated value, 1000 rows of a single value that you are trying to return separately, or what? Some sample data and output might help.

Comment: @MarkBannister: Sorry, it is hard to explain and there is no specific code I could show here. Key problem is: I have a table without index and I must/want/need have to touch every single value of a specific column separately(!). I know that there are better solutions in general, but I want to know how to solve the problem row-by-row and how I can do it as fast as possible without using a cursor. Not because I think cursors are bad in general, I just want to know how to solve it with a good performance with a while-loop.

Comment: @Feroc - You can't. Without any index there is no good way of restarting where you left off so you will need to rescan all the rows you have already processed again. In order to do this deterministically you will also need to apply an `ORDER BY` clause so you will be doing 1,000 sort operations and scanning `500,500` rows. Your temp table technique just simulates what a static cursor does anyway.

Comment: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Comment: @Feroc then I think the answer from Marc Bannister is on the money.  If you are lost then start with a general statement of what you are trying to achieve in functional terms and then follow with what you have tied.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Thanks, guess that was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for avoiding cursors is because you are performing imperative one row at a time operations rather than declarative set based operations.

Replacing a cursor with a while loop will not in itself magically make the performance better and may well make performance worse as you have found out. The difference in performance between the two will depend upon your exact code / table structures and the cursor options you choose [as covered in this series of articles](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2010/05/truth-about-cursors-part-1.html).

To print out all names from the table in a more set based manner you could do

```
DECLARE @Names nvarchar(max);

SELECT @Names = ISNULL(@Names + '
','') + Names
FROM YourTable;

PRINT @Names;
```

Comment: Thanks for the article, another good one from you. Your example would have, of course, the same output in a much faster way, but it wouldn't solve the original problem, as every name should get printed separately (of course it doesn't make any sense in this example).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to execute a function against each value of a specific column in a table is:

```
select MyFunction(ColumnName) from TableName
```